# mongo.so: > undefined symbol: php_json_encode in Unknown on line 0. After installation mongo driver for php

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu

After installation of `Mongo 2.6.0` which was successful, I tried to upgrade `php mongo` driver on `ubuntu 12.04` with the following command: `sudo pecl upgrade mongo`. It started successfully with:

```
downloading mongo-1.5.1.tgz ...
Starting to download mongo-1.5.1.tgz (188,885 bytes)
.........................................done: 188,885 bytes
117 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20121113
Zend Module Api No:      20121212
Zend Extension Api No:   220121212
Build with Cyrus SASL (MongoDB Enterprise Authentication) support? [no]:
```

Where I selected `No` because when I tried yes, it was failing with error. With no I was able to install it successufully and the ending message looked like this:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mongo.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/mongo-1.5.1
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=mongo.so" to php.ini
```

After this I restarted apache (`2.4.9`), but my `phpinfo()` told me that mongo is not installed. On the other hand I can clearly see `extension=mongo.so` in my php.ini.

I checked my error.log and I can see the following line there:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mongo.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/mongo.so:
>   undefined symbol: php_json_encode in Unknown on line 0

I checked my `/usr/lib/php5/20121212/` and saw that there is actually a file `mongo.so`. I googled it and the only similar thing I was able to find is [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/407014/pecl-install-mongo-keeps-compiling-with-wrong-module-api), which is not really relevant, but having no other options I still tried steps there with no success.

Does anyone has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: You should get more upvotes for asking this question!

Comment: I got the PHP Warning above when I accidentally installed php5-mongo out of order by installing it before mongodb, I believe.  So just doing a `sudo apt-get install --reinstall php5-mongo` fixed that warning for me!  The info below is useful as well.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The issue is with the loading order, so the json extension needs to be loaded before `mongo.so` is loaded.

Since others are likely to come across this I will outline the whole process:

- In your `/etc/php/mods-available` directory (or as appropriate to platform) create a separate `mongo.ini` with the following:

```bash
; configuration for php mongo module
; priority=30
extension=mongo.so
```

- Remove any other references to `mongo.so` from other files such as `php.ini`
- Create symlinks in each of the `cli` and `apache2` directories as required for use as so:

> `sudo ln -s ../../mods-available/mongo.ini 30-mongo.ini`

At end of this you should have a structure that looks like this

```bash
$/etc/php5$ tree
.
├── apache2
│   ├── conf.d
│   │   ├── 05-opcache.ini -> ../../mods-available/opcache.ini
│   │   ├── 10-pdo.ini -> ../../mods-available/pdo.ini
│   │   ├── 20-json.ini -> ../../mods-available/json.ini
│   │   ├── 20-readline.ini -> ../../mods-available/readline.ini
│   │   └── 30-mongo.ini -> ../../mods-available/mongo.ini
│   └── php.ini
├── cli
│   ├── conf.d
│   │   ├── 05-opcache.ini -> ../../mods-available/opcache.ini
│   │   ├── 10-pdo.ini -> ../../mods-available/pdo.ini
│   │   ├── 20-json.ini -> ../../mods-available/json.ini
│   │   ├── 20-readline.ini -> ../../mods-available/readline.ini
│   │   └── 30-mongo.ini -> ../../mods-available/mongo.ini
│   └── php.ini
└── mods-available
    ├── json.ini
    ├── mongo.ini
    ├── opcache.ini
    ├── pdo.ini
    └── readline.ini
```

This makes sure that the "json" extension will be loaded by the dynamic loader before the "mongo" module is.

But basically remove the `mongo.so` from "php.ini" and put it in it's own file with higher loading order than the json extension. Then it will work.

This possibly needs a JIRA as I believe it has come up before.

**UPDATE**: Actually is an open JIRA [PHP-1052](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-1052)

Comment: Thank you. I do not have `30-mongo.ini` in that folder. So as far as I got I need to create 30-mongo.ini with extension=mongo.so?

Comment: @SalvadorDali The point is to create a separate ini just for loading the mongo extension. Remove it from php.ini and make sure it is loaded after the json extension. The fact that is is loading before the json extension is loaded is what causes the error.

Comment: I just added `mongo.ini` into `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d` folder. Inside of the folder I only have `extension=mongo.so`. Strangely enough when I restart apache - no errors appear in the log. But there is still no mogno in phpinfo(). Any code which has connection to mongo - gives me an error: `Class 'MongoClient' not found`

Comment: @SalvadorDali I just edited the answer content to make the process a bit clearer. The problem is clearly reproducible by allowing mongo to load first. Make sure you have a structure as shown in order to make sure it is working. And be sure to remove any other reference to `mongo.so`

Comment: Thank you. Amazing reference. And I also learned about `tree` and symbolic links.

Answer (score 5):

my system is centos 6.3. I got the problem solved.

```
vim /etc/php.ini
```

then add

```
extension=json.so
```

before

```
extension=mongo.so
```

at last restart the php-fpm and nginx(apache)

```
service php-fpm restart
service ngxin restart
```

It's OK!

Comment: I have not asked about Centos. In Centos everything works fine, so there is no point of posting this.

Comment: Actually this worked for me on fedora! Thank you @lindy

Answer (score 4):

For someone who is looking for a fast solution, here is my few lines, which utilize Neil's Lunn long explanation about the problem.

```
sudo -i
cd /etc/php5/mods-available/
nano mongo.ini
```

Than insert this:

```
; configuration for php mongo module
; priority=30
extension=mongo.so
```

Go out from the editor.

```
cd ../cli/conf.d
sudo ln -s ../../mods-available/mongo.ini 30-mongo.ini
cd ../../apache2/conf.d
sudo ln -s ../../mods-available/mongo.ini 30-mongo.ini
```

Restart apache.

```
service apache2 restart
```

Everything should work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to load the json extension before the mongo extension.

Don't put any reference to both modules in php.ini,

Create the file mongo.ini inside /etc/php5/mods-enable with the following content:

```
priority=30
extension=mongo.so
```

and the json.ini

```
priority=20
extension=json.so
```

Answer (score 0):

For CentOS, you will just need to add the mongo.ini in the php module directory, in my case:

```
"/etc/php.d/"
```

Comment: The question is about ubuntu. Moreover, how to do this on CentOs is the same how it was for previous versions and is outlined in a lot of places.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 14.04 you can also add a "30-mongo.ini" symlink under these:

```
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d
/etc/php5/fmp/conf.d
```