# Mongodb connection in PHP not working

Tags: php, linux, mongodb, xampp

I am using Ubuntu **12.04 LTS** and installed pecl in `/opt/lampp/bin/` .

When installing second time its throwing error -

Command run previously -

`pecl install mongo`

> pecl/mongo is already installed and is the same as the released
>   version 1.5.1 install failed

Now when I am Checking by -

`echo extension_loaded("mongo") ? "loaded\n" : "not loaded\n";`

It is showing not Loaded.

However I updated the php.ini with `extension=mongo.so` and restarted the server, but its not working.

Let me now what I am doing wrong.

**EDIT**

I re instantiated the command and following is the outcome -

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mongo.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/mongo-1.5.1
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=mongo.so" to php.ini
```

Comment: Did you update the right php.ini?

Comment: This [**error**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22952994/2313887) ?

Comment: @Sammaye I updated the one located in /opt/lampp/etc php.ini

Comment: @NeilLunn This is my php.ini http://pastebin.com/sYDipjaS

Comment: I was asking are you seeing the error as shown in the linked question? There is a dependency issue with the 1.5.1 driver that requires the `json` extension to be loaded first. So if this is not statically linked to you PHP build then you likely have exactly that problem.

Comment: @NeilLunn I dont think it will work in my case as I am using XAMPP so I searched in my php.ini and nothing like json propagated..also I dont have those kind of folder structures in my etc

Comment: You will not have **exactly** the same folder structures but the principles will be the same. Check for json loaded, it should be there, if not then install it. There will be an ini that specifies this as a dynamic load if this is the case. The principle is to ensure the mongo extension is loaded after the json extension in order to resolve the dependency. It is the same error in your logs yes?

Comment: @NeilLunn I checked the logs and found `[01-May-2014 10:06:32 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mongo.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mongo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally with the help of [Neil Lunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2313887/neil-lunn) I made it the right way.

I added the full path and added the code at the very last line of my `php.ini`

> extension="/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mongo.so"

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution for xampp in ubntu linux.

If this command not work for you `pecl install mongo`

you should type below command

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install mongo
```