# The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled

Tags: mongodb

I had run command

similar questions I got here
[Mongodb connection in PHP not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404462/mongodb-connection-in-php-not-working/24185985#24185985)

but not resolved by that solution.

`pecl install mongo`

> pecl/mongo is already installed and is the same as the released
>   version 1.5.3 install failed

Now when I am Checking by -

`echo extension_loaded("mongo") ? "loaded\n" : "not loaded\n";`

It is showing not Loaded.

However I updated the php.ini with `extension=mongo.so` and restarted the server, but its not working.

Let me know what I am doing wrong.

**EDIT**

I re instantiated the command and following is the outcome -

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mongo.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/mongo-1.5.3
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=mongo.so" to php.ini
```

Its not showing in phpinfo file also.

when i run this command

`pecl list` root@helloworld:~# pecl list Installed packages, channel
 pecl.php.net:
 =========================================

```
Package Version State 
mongo   1.5.3   stable  
propro  1.0.0   stable
raphf   1.0.4   stable`
```

Comment: 1. Are you sure you updated the right php.ini, 2. Have you restarted any PHP services if you are using any, i.e. fpm?

Comment: Yes..I am sure i had updated right php.ini file and restarted server.

Comment: Closed as duplicate since you posted the same answer to that question as the one you posted here that I deleted.

Comment: Updated Question please make it positive...this cant resolve my issue..so i posted question.