# php_ini not set to php.ini location

Tags: php, mongodb, php-ini

I'm trying to install MongoDB PHP Driver for XAMPP on OSX, and my terminal says the following:

```
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it (if it's even  problem at all)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404462/mongodb-connection-in-php-not-working

Comment: That's use less, it's for Ubuntu

Comment: The line `configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location` is always followed by another one telling you what is wrong, please, provide it. Most likely to be the solution indicated by @Maximus2012

Answer (score 34):

`pear config-set php_ini /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

Comment: It says ok saved the config, but running the install after it results the same on php docker box

Comment: Use `pear config-set` instead of `pecl config-set` for automatic pecl installs.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using XAMPP included pecl version, you should use following command on your cli:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/bin/pecl config-set php_ini /Applications/XAMPP/etc/php.ini
```